# paginate_links() don't properly work in search.php?

Tags: functions, permalinks, pagination, search, paginate-links

I'm using this in my search.php template …

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php echo get_pagination_links(); ?>
</div>
```

And this is the function …

```
function get_pagination_links() {
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;

    return paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next'    => false
    ) );
}
```

-

The output works: So if I search for "test" and there are more then 10 results and the pagination shows `1 2` where `2` is a link. When clicking page `2` the address bar correctly updates to `mysite.com/search/test/page/2` but the resulting page is still number `1`.

There are still the same results as on page number `1` and the pagination links are still the same - `2` is the still the link and `1` is the current page.

Any ideas why that could happen?

**Update**

Here is where the custom function is called in the template:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <hgroup class="section-heading wrapper">
        <h1>Results</h1>
    </hgroup>

    <section id="results">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <ul class="event-items">
                <?php get_template_part( 'inc/search', 'result' ); ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </section>

    <div class="pagination tiny wrapper">
        <?php echo get_pagination_links(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Nothing found</h2>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

#### Edit

Using recommended code from the answer below:

```
/**
 * Pagination links for search and archives
 */

function get_pagination_links() {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
    $big = 999999999;

    return paginate_links( array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => $current,
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next'    => false
    ) );
}
```

The pagination is working now however the "permalinks" are not exactly what I want them to be. I use `custom_pagination_base()` to have the this permalink structure:

- `mypage.com/search/term/seite/2` (where seite is the german word for page).

Is it possible to keep the permalinks working like that. The paginaton works with your code, just the permalinks look like this:

- `mypage.com/search/term?paged=2`

Comment: Show the query for this request.

Comment: I updated my question with my `search.php` template. There is no loop inside the `search-result.php` just plain html.

Comment: Did you peruse [the previous questions related to **`paginate_links()`**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=paginate_links)?

Comment: I read and googled quite a while but can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is answered elsewhere, but I'll add it here again.

I believe your issue lies here:

```
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
```

Try this instead:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
```

...then:

```
'current' => $current;
```

Your `'base'` may also be an issue. Instead of this:

```
$big = 999999999;
//...
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) )
```

I use this:

```
'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%')
```

#### Edit

In case it's helpful, here's my entire `paginate_links()` wrapper function:

```
/**
 * Paginate Archive Index Page Links
 */
function oenology_get_paginate_archive_page_links( $type = 'plain', $endsize = 1, $midsize = 1 ) {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;  
    $current = get_query_var( 'paged' ) > 1 ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    // Sanitize input argument values
    if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'plain', 'list', 'array' ) ) ) $type = 'plain';
    $endsize = absint( $endsize );
    $midsize = absint( $midsize );

    // Setup argument array for paginate_links()
    $pagination = array(
        'base'      => @add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
        'format'    => '',
        'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current'   => $current,
        'show_all'  => false,
        'end_size'  => $endsize,
        'mid_size'  => $midsize,
        'type'      => $type,
        'prev_text' => '&lt;&lt;',
        'next_text' => '&gt;&gt;'
    );

    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ).'page/%#%/', 'paged' );

    if ( ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['s'] ) )
        $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );

    return paginate_links( $pagination );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Perfect, but one last little thingy. I updated my question above with your code. The pagination is working now however the "permalinks" are not exactly what I want them to be. I use `custom_pagination_base()` to have the this permalink structure `mypage.com/search/term/seite/2` where `seite` is the german word for page. Is it possible to keep the permalinks working like that. The paginaton works with your code, just the permalinks look like this: `mypage.com/search/term?paged=2`

Comment: See updated answer. I've added my entire function. Also: be careful with how you edit your question. If you overwrite your original code, it's difficult for later readers to follow the question-answer flow. It's usually better to *retain* the original code and then to *add* new code to the question. I'll edit your question to give you an idea what I mean.

Comment: To address your specific follow-up question, refer to the `$pagination['base']` ternary near the end of the function. I *think* you should be able to adapt that line to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, However I seem to have some problem elsewhere. When using your code the pagination won't work again - exact same behaviour as mentioned in my question above. The link clicked doesn't update the view and the pagination doesn't work. If I uncomment your last two `if` blocks in your function (the lines regarding the pemalinks) your function works fine again. So everything works fine except for the part with the rewriting of `?paged` in the url itself. Any other ideas where that could come from? Thanks again for your awesome help so far.

Comment: I suspect the problem is your custom rewrite rules. That's the part of my function that you've changed...

Comment: Just tried this and `get_query_var('paged')` alone works fine. No need to draw this one out of the global.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't a solution using your exact code perhaps you can try using [this](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin) pagination technique as opposed to the example you have used from the WordPress Codec

At a guess I'd say the issue lies with you getting the template part with this line of code:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'inc/search', 'result' ); ?>
```

If this doesn't solve your issue I'd look at bringing the content from 'inc/search' and include it in your search results page without using `<?php get_template_part(); ?>` - it might help you spot any oddities

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's not the `get_template_part()` because I've also tried inserting the code of the template directly into the loop. And the pagination technique you posted in your comment doesn't make a difference - same effect.