# paginate_links refers to "Not Found" page

Tags: wp-query, paginate-links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [paginate_links() don’t properly work in search.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63833/paginate-links-dont-properly-work-in-search-php)

I'm trying to make a simple pagination nav menu, using the following code:

```
global $wp_query;
                    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

                    if($total_pages > 1) {

                        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

                        echo paginate_links(array(
                            'base'  =>  get_pagenum_link(1).'%_%',
                            'format'    =>  'page/%#%',
                            'current'   =>  $current_page,
                            'total'     =>  $total_pages,
                            'prev_next' =>  false,
                            'type'      =>  'list'

                        ));
                    }
```

But when I click on a page link it's reffering me to:

**Not Found**

**The requested URL /wptest/page/2 was not found on this server.**

I know that it's probably something simple that I missed but I don't know what is it.

Comment: Did you check [any of the other questions/answers related to `paginate_links()` pagination issues](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=paginate_links)?

Comment: Yes, I just spent additional hour reading the already asked questions and there isn't a simple answer to this one. Most of them are hacks and additional functions and I just want to use the built in `paginate_links` function.

I supposed that there will be a new official and simple way of doing the pagination thingie..

Comment: This is very hard to answer without more details. Where are you placing the code?

For example if you are trying to add pagination to a custom post type it requires some extra "hacks" to support that.

The base and format arguments should be fixed though, that's for sure....

Here is an example of the code I would use if you want to test it out: https://gist.github.com/wpexplorer/6a42aadeb87934d31a4172983077d01e