# paginate_links WP function

Tags: pagination

I am having a hard time understanding how exactly [`paginate_links`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)  works. I have read the documentation and used it a hundred times before, but I still do not get it fully. Especially 'base' attribute. More exactly, I had this:

```
'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
```

Which was adding /page/2 to the URL. Then I changed it to this:

```
'base'          => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
```

And now it is adding a GET parameter like this: &paged=5

Can anyone link me to a tutorial or an explanation of how the different attributes change the behaviour of the function, and how do they create the actual pagination?

Comment: This one inspired me to write the question:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63833/paginate-links-dont-properly-work-in-search-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the purpose of the function is not *that* hard: generate a set of URLs of a `total` size with `current` page and some pretty parts.

The issue is that the way URL is configured is quite... original and [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) doesn't quite describe what happens accurately.

The documentation implies that these are default `base` and `format` arguments:

```
echo '<pre>', esc_html( paginate_links( [
    'base'    => '%_%',
    'format'  => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => 1,
    'total'   => 3,
    'type'    => 'plain',
] ) ), '</pre>';

<span class='page-numbers current'>1</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='?page=2'>2</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href='?page=3'>3</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="?page=2">Next »</a>
```

That's not actually true. The default `base` and `format` are generated dynamically, depending on site's configuration. For my dev site they would be like this:

```
echo '<pre>', esc_html( paginate_links( [
    'base'    => 'http://dev.rarst.net/%_%',
    'format'  => 'page/%#%/',
    'current' => 1,
    'total'   => 3,
    'type'    => 'plain',
] ) ), '</pre>';

<span class='page-numbers current'>1</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='http://dev.rarst.net/page/2/'>2</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href='http://dev.rarst.net/page/3/'>3</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="http://dev.rarst.net/page/2/">Next »</a>
```

So what happens there? Two things:

1. `%#%` in `format` is replaced with current page number.
2. Then `%_%` in `base` is replaced with format result.

So for page `2`:

1. `2` + `page/%#%/` = `page/2/`
2. `page/2/` + `http://dev.rarst.net/%_%` = `http://dev.rarst.net/page/2/`

Rest of the arguments deals with "pretty" stuff like splitting into segments and such (so that you don't actually show 1000 links for 1000 pages).

So I guess the summary is: the function is *very* flexible and allows to build wildly different pagination schemes. But you really need to have specific goal in mind to build `base` and `format` correctly.

There are some higher level wrappers, that were added later and are more specific to the tasks, for example [`the_posts_pagination()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Have you ever used any other scheme apart from page/2 and ?paged=2? What else can we use?

Comment: I don't think I ever had a practical use cases that called for a completely custom pagination. WP generally handles everything for its own items and CPTs. Custom pagination is realm of solutions that need to query something very not–WP–ish.